# @required annotation don't work properly on Flutter App using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final String textButton;

  const RoundedButton(
      {Key key, @required this.backgroundColor, @required this.textButton})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: backgroundColor ?? Colors.grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
      width: getWidthByPercent(context, 90),
      height: getWidthByPercent(context, 15),
      child: Text(
        textButton ?? "",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: getWidthByPercent(context, 7),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I use this widget on another page, the widget not warning me about the required parameters:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: getHeightByPercent(context, 60),
      bottom: getHeightByPercent(context, 1),
      left: getHeightByPercent(context, 1),
      right: getHeightByPercent(context, 1),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: whiteDefault,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "SDS Connect",
              style: initialTitle(context, 10),
            ),
            Text(
              "The first to connect you with the information you need through NFC technology and innovate cloud based solutions",
              style: softGray(context, 5),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            RoundedButton()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Have some way to use this? I use this thing someway on others projects, but I don't remember how I was used, there's something that I can import on pubsbec.yaml.

**UPDATE**

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and for some reason they not show the warning on the call of widget `RoundedButton()` but only on dart analyses windows, there's some way to show on widget call?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't any IDE bug? I've tested your code here and it explicitly tells me that:
`The parameter 'textButton' is required.dart(missing_required_param)` and `The parameter 'backgroundColor' is required.`

Just a quick reminder: they're **warnings**, so no compile-time errors should be thrown.

Comment: By any chance, do you have other class named `RoundedButton` as well? He could've imported from another file.